Identify this courtroom drama for me
Definitely an American movie, probably came out in the last 10 or 15 years.  I just remember towards the end the lead character, who appeared to have some kind of handicap (I think a stutter or something) is talking to his lawyer in a jail cell.  Whatever that handicap was, it turns out he didn't really have it at all and was faking.  I'm almost positive he had been accused of murder.
I remember the character was played by a major actor, I thought it was Leonardo Dicaprio but I looked at his movies on IMDB and none looked familiar.

You're definitely looking for Primal Fear, starring Richard Gere as the lawywer and Edward Norton (who might get confused with DiCaprio) as his client:

Courtroom thriller about a slick, hotshot lawyer who takes the seemingly unwinnable case of a young altar boy accused of murdering an eminent catholic priest.

In fact Edward Norton's character has a stuttering problem and seems to be a very shy guy. During the case he later reveals a second, stronger and more evil, personality and gets declared criminally insane and thus effectively freed of the crime, as his lawyer achieves to convice the jury that his second personality commited the murder. But at the end he reveals to his lawyer (in his jail cell) that the whole image of the shy stuttering guy with the split personality was all acted out right from the beginning and he actually commited the murder with full conciousness.

Personal favourite of mine, especially love the soundtrack.

That's it!  Thanks a ton!!

I believe this movie is Primal Fear.Rich performances by both actors,
Richard Gere and Edward Norton.
  You gave a good description from what you could remember of the movie's plotline.I hope this was helpful to you also.

Hi Pamela. Notice that this answer was already posted and accepted. There's no need to post it again.
